# Wear os accelerometer and bluetooth low energy scanning

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, wear-os, accelerometer

Maybe someone works with **wear os** and native elements as Bluetooth low energy (BLE) and accelerometer. I can't find the necessary information in the official doc - https://developer.android.com/wear.

The questions are:

- is it possible to get accelerometer data with a specific frequency;
- is it possible to do BLE scanner on the wear os;
- maybe you know specific problems with these elements on the wear os

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question does seems to Needs more focus, please consider the guidelines [*"Why are some questions closed??"*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop "standard" Android applications on Wear OS, most of the differences are in the different lifecycles, but apart from that you can use the same approach you would use on Android:

- To get accelerometer values you can refer to [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview). Bear in mind that the frequency at which you receive updates is hard to control (differs per different devices) with the field in sensorManager.registerListener(). What you can do is to filter yourself when you receive the updates;
- To scan for BLE devices you can use part of the code at [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html), up to Find BLE devices.

Comment: okay, thanks, have you met problems with these services in the background mode? Is it reliable to work a couple of hours?

Comment: On Android no, you have to create a Foreground service [https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground]. On Wear OS I don't know yet, I believe you should use always-on apps [https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on] or watch faces [https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces]. I'll test both in the upcoming weeks.